# ValidatorCalloutExtender Alert box

Tags: .net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Is there any way to make a ValidatorCalloutExtender popup a standard alert box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is the alert the validation results you do not need the ValidatorCalloutExtender for this.  You can use the standard .Net ValidationSummary like this:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="tb1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Click" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="validateEmptyText"
        ControlToValidate="tb1"
        Display="None"
        ErrorMessage="Required field is missing." />
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="True" ShowSummary="False" />
```